# MLflow - TypeError: Only dict and DataFrame input types are supported

Tags: python, dataframe, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, mlflow

I'm fairly new to the software MLflow and I'm trying to make an HTTP POST request to the served model I developed but the error up in the title appears.

Here's the situation.
I use as a backend storage a SQLite db and as an artifact storage a local folder.
The command to run the mlflow server is the following (the model is in the Staging stage):
`mlflow models serve -m "models:/nuovo_modello/Staging" -p 1234`

I registered the model on MLflow and this is the model schema:

[image]

When I try to make a POST request as follows (as suggested in the TF serving guide: https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/api_rest#request_format_2)
`{ "instances": [ [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4]] }`

or even in the JSON Content-Type as follows:
`curl http://127.0.0.1:1234/invocations -H "Content-Type: application/json; format=pandas-split" -d '{"columns":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99], "data":[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,3,1,4]]}'`

I get this error and I don't really know what's causing it:

> {"error_code": "BAD_REQUEST", "message": "Encountered an unexpected error while evaluating the model. Verify that the serialized input Dataframe is compatible with the model for inference.", "stack_trace": "Traceback [...]

> File "/Path/to/the/file/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/tensorflow.py", line 584, in predict\n    raise TypeError(f"Only dict and DataFrame input types are supported}")\nTypeError: Only dict and DataFrame input types are supported

The data it's causing this error is not a `DataFrame` nor a `dict` but is a `numpy.ndarray` instead (I checked it with a type(...) while debugging).

The shape of the inputs are correct but I really don't know how to solve this. It seems MLflow converts the data into the numpy.ndarray without any reason

Thanks in advance to anyone who'll help me

Answer (score 1):

The first example ("instances": ) is TF Serving JSON format that is not supported by MLflow.

Try adding double quotes to the column names in the "pandas-split" examples.

Comment: In what way TF serving JSON is not supported? Here in the MLflow docs says I can query my model in that format -> https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/models.html#deploy-mlflow-models
I used that format as the body of a POST HTTP Request with Postman

Comment: I already tried what you said about the pandas-split choice but it outputs me the same error.